# Mapping many-to-many relation for class inheritance  in Hibernate/NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

In the most simplified version , here is my problem
[image]

```
public class D{
 public List<A> ListofA {get;set;}
}

public interface A{
}

public class B implements A{
}

public class C implements A{
}
```

`class B` maps to *Table B*
`class C` maps to *Table C*

**A is just an interface and is not mapped to any table.**

**How do I define the polymorphic (`many-to-many`) association between D -> A**

I am using `NHibernate` with `FluentMapping`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attemped to answer my own question.
However I would like to find out **BETTER/ MORE RATIONAL** solution to this problem.

Here is my solution:

### Redesign `Class D`

I redesign `class D` as

```
      public class D {
              public List<MagicObj> ListofA {get;set;}
      }

       //New Entity added which was not there in the question before.
       public class MagicObj{
              public A   ActualEntity{get;set;}
       }
```

NO changes in the remaining entities.

```
         public interface A{

         }

         public class B implements A{

         }

         public class C implements A{

         }
```

This design change should allow me to map

### Fluent Mapping

for the above redesigned class structure

```
D->MagicObj as HasMany(x=>x.ListofA)
MagicObj->A as ReferenceAny(x=>x.ActualEntity)
                    .EntityIdentifierColumn("EntityType")
                    .EntityIdentifierColumn("EntityId");
```

Guess I choose to use add a new relation between `Class D` and `Class A` is that
I was not able to find a way to map it directly in Fluent.